# Difference of (UINavigationController&UIViewController) perform dismissViewControllerAnimated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I want to know the difference between`UINavigationController` and`UIViewController`,while they both perform selector`dismissViewControllerAnimated`.
the fact is that they all works. I did it like this:

**Code:**

```
UIViewController *vc = [UIViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
[self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And in the new controller,I did this:

```
// self.navigationController to dismiss
[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
// self to dismiss
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

both they works well,but i do not know the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let consider the first case

```
[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

navigation controller is root view controller and you r explicitly calling the dismiss with root view controller.which you can say container view controller

Let consider second case

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

In this case you are dismissing the child viewcontroller,which is embeded in container view controller.
Suppose now after presenting you push a view controller, Now when you call `dismissViewControllerAnimated` it dismiss the both the presented and push one.

Answer (score 0):

Well first off, a `UINavigationController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`, and `UIViewController` has the ability to present views modally.  So you can present from both classes.

When a `UIViewController` embedded in a `UINavigationController` is visible, essentially both the `UIViewController` and the `UINavigationController` are both visible at the same time, and both can technically present another view modally.

Presenting a view modally is usually meant to stop whatever you were doing previously in order to do something else, and then go back to where you left off - for example, changing a setting.

Since you are leaving both view controllers to do something else, it really doesn't matter which one you present from.  However, the `presentingViewController` will be different depending on which one you present from, so if you need that property at all, it matters.

Perhaps it might be best if the modal view controller relates to the `UIViewController` in some way rather than the `UINavigationController` to have it present, but that's really just a style thing.

Comment: thanks very much,and i learn a lot.  but I concern more about dismissViewControllerAnimated.